# 403 from a http request to a Cloudflare hosted website

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, cloudflare, http-status-code-403

I use axios to parse a website and I get this error:

Error: Request failed with status code 403

I tried to set a custom user-agent but no luck

```
module.exports.get_output = function (url) {
axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: url,
    headers: {User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_2_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.192 Safari/537.36'}
})
    .then(function (res) {
        console.log(res)
    })
}
```

I know it's a Cloudflare website but I couldn't find a way to bypass this - most recommendations suggest pretending to be a browser but I tried that too.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Cloudflare is not API friendly, I solved it by disabling "Browser Integrity Check" in Cloudflare Dashboard.

Related discussion: https://community.cloudflare.com/t/api-403-after-enabling-cloudflare/108078/6